# How many ways are there to evaluate expression to true?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

> given a string that includes the characters ['T','F', '|', '&', '^'], such that between every two expressions (T, F), there is an operand (|,^,&), how many ways are there to put parentheses in the expression to make it True?

I go along with the recursive approach, I did a `for` loop that splits the expression string at every position, meaning for the string `"T|F^T"`, at the first level of the recursion it would make two calls with `"T"`, `"F^T"` and `"T|F"`, `"T"`.

The base case is when the string is of length 1, the number of ways would be 1 if the expression is `"T"`, and 0 if the expression is `"F"`.

I'm having a hard time calculating the total ways to reach a true expression.

The code is as follows:

```
bool exp(string e)
{
    return e=="T";
}
bool calc(bool a, bool b, char para)
{
    bool ans;
    if(para =='|') ans= a|b;
    else if(para == '&') ans= a&&b;
    else ans= a^b;
    return ans;
}
bool cntExpr(string A, int &countsub, int &cnt)
{
   // cout<<A<<endl;
    if(A.length()==1)
        if(exp(A))
        {
            countsub=1;
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            countsub =0;
            return false;
        }
    for(int i = 1;i<A.length();i+=2) //1,3,5 ->operand positions 
    {
        string l , r;
        int leftcnt=0, rightcnt=0;
        l = A.substr(0, i);
        r = A.substr(i+1,A.length()-(i+1));
        char operand = A[i];
        bool left = cntExpr(l,leftcnt, cnt);
        bool right = cntExpr(r,rightcnt, cnt);
        countsub = leftcnt+rightcnt;
        if(calc(left, right, operand))
            cnt+=countsub;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: *I'm having a hard time calculating the total ways to reach a true expression.* This is a bit vague. What exactly are you having a problem with? I would suggest that you try to break the problem up into smaller parts. When you can see more clearly what exactly you're having issues with you can ask a more specific question and it will be much easier to help you. Right now, someone could just hand you a working solution which defeats the purpose quite a bit.

Comment: let's take the example of  'one level upon' the base cases when the left expression was 'T' and the right expression was 'F' and the operator between them is "^". "T" gave us 1 and "F" gave us 0 => number of ways. now, I check whether the current expression returns a True and I find out it is, cause "T^F" is True. how do I calculate the total ways it took to get to this current True statement?

Comment: are `(T && T)` and `((T && T))` two different ways to put bracktes?

Comment: no, I'ts the same expression

Comment: The simple and brute force approach is to try to put brackets in all possible ways you can, then check 1) How many different ways can you put brackets and 2) How many of them result in true. The is usually done by a recursive approach. But to simplify the problem I would suggest that you start by just parsing the string and splitting it up into some form that's easier to deal with so you can do the recursive brute-force search on. I's just not clear here if you just have no idea how to start at all or if there is a specific part of this that you are having issues with.